# My Insinkerator Model HWT has been leaking water out of the right vent tube

Tags: water, leak

My Insinkerator Model HWT has been leaking water out of the right vent tube after each use, and it is leaking down the casing. How can I  repair it?

Comment: I believe the vent tube is a flexible plastic tube and can be replaced. (*or the end trimmed to repair*)  If it is leaking from the top connection You will need to UN-install the handle. I know on the older units you can access the stub that the tube is pushed onto but not sure on new ones. You should contact Insinkerator for advise. **The leak could be from another connection in the handle and it is  just running down the tube**.

Comment: Do you mean the drain tube? Did you take out the knockout inside?